# awk and cat - How to ignore multiple lines?

Tags: filter, sed, awk, cat

I need to extract Voip log from a D-Link router, so I've setup a little python script that executes a command in this router via telnet.
My script does a "cat /var/log/calls.log" and returns the result, however...
it also sends non-important stuff, like the BusyBox banner, etc...
How can I ignore lines from 1 to 6 and the last 2 ?
This is my current output:

```
yaba@foobar:/stuff$ python calls.py


BusyBox v1.00 (2009.04.09-11:17+0000) Built-in shell (msh)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

DVA-G3170i/PT # cat /var/call.log
1         ,1294620563,2  ,+351xxx080806  ,xxx530802      ,1  ,3  ,1
DVA-G3170i/PT # exit
```

And I just need:

```
1         ,1294620563,2  ,+351xxx080806  ,xxx530802      ,1  ,3  ,1
```

(it can have multiple lines)
So that I can save it to a CSV and later to a sql db.

Thanks, and sorry my bad english.

Comment: I think  **head** and **tail** are better than AWK for this one ...

Comment: If you can guarantee that the header will always be exactly the same length and the tail will too, then ... it's still launching three heavyweight processes and piping them together.  AWK is a tool designed **SPECIFICALLY** for this kind of work and it does it well, provided you spend fifteen minutes to learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a pattern in AWK to match the text you want?

```
python calls.py | awk '/^[0-9]/{print}/'
```

The whole **POINT** of AWK is matching lines based on patterns and manipulating/printing those matched lines.

---

***Edited to add example run.***

Here's a junk data file based on your sample above.

```
$ cat junk.dat


BusyBox v1.00 (2009.04.09-11:17+0000) Built-in shell (msh)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

DVA-G3170i/PT # cat /var/call.log
1         ,1294620563,2  ,+351xxx080806  ,xxx530802      ,1  ,3  ,1
DVA-G3170i/PT # exit
```

Here's running it through AWK with a filter.

```
$ cat junk.dat | awk '/^[0-9]/ {print}'
1         ,1294620563,2  ,+351xxx080806  ,xxx530802      ,1  ,3  ,1
```

No need for SED, no need for counting lines, no need for anything but AWK.  Why make things more complicated than they need to be?

Comment: +1 Another advantage of using AWK: look at all those fields just ripe for the picking! `awk -F, '/^[0-9]/ {print $1,$3,$4}'` for example.

Comment: Indeed.  You could do a whole lot more than just copying lines.  You could extract what you need from it, format it nicely, wrap it up in a bow and hand it on with a smile.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.
The problem with awk is between the chair and the keyboard, and that would be me :) I must RTF awk M.

Comment: It's worth reading the manual for awk.  It's not that big a language but it packs some real power in its problem domain (which is line-oriented text manipulation).

Answer (score 1):

In one call to `sed`:

```
sed -n '1,6d;7,${N;$q;P;D}'
```

or for picky versions of `sed`:

```
sed -ne '1,6d' -e '7,${N' -e '$q' -e 'P' -e 'D}'
```

You could also do it based on matches:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]+/p'
```

or something similar.

But why doesn't your Python script read the file and do the filtering (instead of calling an external utility)?

Comment: I think AWK is the better tool for line-oriented work like log files and the like, but this--especially the last one with matches--does the job without the weird gyrations people are suggesting.

Comment: Because telnetlib doesn't let me :|

Answer (score 0):

#### python calls.py | sed -e 1,6d -e '$d'

---

So that might work. It will filter out the first 6 and the last, which is what your example indicates you need. If you really want to clobber the last two lines then you could do:

```
python calls.py | sed -e 1,6d -e '$d' | sed -e '$d'
```

#### But wait ... you said awk, so...

```
python calls.py | awk '{ if(NR > 7) { print t }; t = $0 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '1,6d;$!N;$d;P;D' file
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it (maybe D-Link router has FTP or SSH support) but you can do it with awk:

```
awk '/cat/, /exit/' | sed -e '1d' -e '$d'
```

awk will print everything between lines containing "cat" and "exit", unfortunately including these two lines. That's what the remaining commands are for, I couldn't figure out how to do it nicer than that...

Comment: You know about regular expression matching in AWK and you couldn't think of maybe matching on the values you want?

Comment: How am I supposed to know what the format of all the records is? I actually think my solution is the best out of all of them here...

Comment: You eyeball the file and figure it out?  If it's even slightly useful as a format it will have regular patterns.  If you can't see those patterns I'm not sure that programming is your best choice in avocations....